# Cursing oneself in Islam

Tags: dua

Sometimes when a family member irritates me too much, I get into a rage and say things like this:

> may Allah kill me tonight or may Allah make me die today, etc.

After a while when I cool down, I really regret what I've said. I feel annoyed and don't know what to do. I say "Auzo bellahe mena'shaytane rajeem (اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم)."

Does this mean my bad prayers will also be answered? Is there a way to expiate for such curses? Thank you and Jazakumullah.

Comment: You should be careful what you pray for because even curses are sometimes answer, especially that of a mother towards their child. Try not to make a negative du'a for yourself or anyone else. When you have calmed down the best thing to do is ask Allah for forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Totally, cursing is counted as an unethical and as an impermissible practice. Meanwhile, it is declared that La’n is considered as a haram (forbidden) act unless in the mentioned-items in accordance with Islam.

According to a hadith it is narrated that:

- > Believer (faithful person) doesn’t include the persons who curse.
  >   (Namely: does not curse (expect the items which Islam allows …)
  >
  > (محدث نورى : مستدرك الوسائل ، ج 11، ص 178، ح 12686.)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his household) … said: Of
  >   Mo’men’s (believer) characteristics is that he (or she) is not curser
  >   (does not curse)
  >
  > (محدث نورى : مستدرك الوسائل ، ج 11، ص 179، ح 12686)

It is haram for cursing the Mo’men (believer) and whoever is not deserved it. Eventually in regard to the Kaffarah of that, as much as I made research, apparently the best Kaffarah of is repentance. In truth, you’d better repent and decide not to try it again. In the meanwhile, you look as a believer, consequently you are not allow to curse a believer (Mo’men). And as the final recommendation, endeavor not to do something to make your family (especially your parents) furious in order to stopping placing in that situation that…

---

**References:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=234126)
- [www.faraghlit.com](http://www.faraghlit.com/%D8%AC%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A8%D9%91-%D9%88-%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%82%D8%B1%E2%80%8C%D8%A2%D9%86-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%B1/)
- [akhlagh.porsemani.ir](http://akhlagh.porsemani.ir/node/1148)

.